# Change date format in formula to MM/DD/YY

Tags: formula, date, format, date-field

I have a formula that uses a date field that returns a date with a format DD/MM/YYYY. I need to change the format of this date to DD/MM/YY.

```
TEXT(DAY(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))+"." +TEXT(MONTH(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))+"." +TEXT(YEAR(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))
```

Is it possible to do it in the formula or do I need to code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do something like this `RIGHT(TEXT(YEAR(NOW())), 2)` to just take last 2 digits

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Mod()` to convert 4 digit year to 2 digits.

DD/MM/YY

```
TEXT(DAY(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))+"/" +TEXT(MONTH(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))+"/" +TEXT(MOD(YEAR(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c),100))
```

MM/DD/YY

```
TEXT(MONTH(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))+"/" +TEXT(DAY(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c))+"/" +TEXT(MOD(YEAR(ExpectedDeliveryDate__c),100))
```

Comment: thank you, it worked !