# Converting Date/Time to Dates in reporting?

Tags: datetime, custom-report-type, formatting

I have a report I'm running where one of the columns is Case CreatedDate, which defaults to a DateTime format like 9/10/2021, 11:44 AM.

Is there a way to apply formatting to this so it could show in the report as m/d/yy (example, 9/3/21)?

Thanks

Comment: you can create new formula field with type `Date` and use it in your report

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Formula Field of type = Formula(Date) in Case object.

Then in the formula write:

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)
```

In the case you prefer your own Date format to standard Salesforce.
You need to change Formula Field to Type = Formula (Text) instead and then follow the answer below.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/293056/38191

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, but it will just give me 9/3/2021, rather that 9/3/21. Any way around that?

Comment: @user1702965 updated my answer